# iPhone 4 Simulator for Xcode 6

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

I need to simulate an iPhone 4 (NOT iPhone 4S). I get a whole list of iPhones but "4" isn't one of them.

Pulling my hair out having Googled for an hour now, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

I also tried messing with build settings to no avail...

Comment: Xcode doesn't have support for an iPhone 4 simulator. Bring up the Devices window and tap the + at the bottom to add a new simulator. There you can see the possible choices. iPhone 4 is not one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option for iPhone 4.  What difference do you expect between the iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s simulators to warrant its inclusion?  There was no such distinction in older versions of the iPhone Simulator which had just "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)".

Comment: Very much in agreement. The important differences -- primarily horsepower -- are not something the simulator can help one with.

Comment: My clients are all specifically using iPhone 4. So if I do testing with the iPhone 4S simulator, in theory there are no differences? That sounds like a fine solution if true, it's just I wanted to try and match my client base as closely as possible...

Comment: Yup, I just did some Googling. So the 4S is faster, better camera, better antenna, but essentially the same phone - same resolution, a few less bells and whistles in iOS support, like no Siri... But thanks Jeremy I'll take that as the solution - just test on iPhone 4S and thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Well, iphone 4 simulator is lighter than 4S. It's near to impossible simulate an iphone 4s on macmini or macbook pro 2011.

Comment: What do you mean by "iphone 4 simulator" and "lighter"?

Comment: I mean faster. I believe it's just like emulating a windows xp or 7, a ps2 or ps3. It needs more resource to be emulated or simulated. Maybe I'm wrong because we don't have the a new iphone 4 simulator, but the old one was faster.

Comment: Well first or all, it is an API level simulator, not an emulator.  All processes run on and at the native speed of your desktop processor.  I guarantee you the old one was not faster as the code that is run (for the iOs 7.x runtimes) is 100% unchanged.

Comment: there are differences between iphone4 or iphone4s or they wouldn't cost £200 more

Comment: But those differences are all hardware differences.  They are not differences that could expose themselves in the iOS Simulator.  This is the same reason why we did not include a profile for the iPad Air 2 until iOS 9 made it behave differently than an iPad Air.