# How can I add iPhone 4 to the list of devices in iOS Simulator (Xcode 6.1)?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6

**EDIT**: Sorry, it is a duplicate.

**Original Question**:

The following appear as choices for device within XCode (6.1), but there is no iPhone 4. How can I add this? (A bug is being reported against 7.1.2 on iPhone 4 and I am looking for a way to test it without a physical device).

[image]

Comment: This won't help you very much as it's only a simulator. If you cannot reproduce the bug on the 4S simulator, you should consider getting a real iPhone 4.

Comment: i think u can't get in xcode 6.1

Comment: Xcode 6 has iOS8 SDK which is not supported for iPhone4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 Simulator for Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069133/iphone-4-simulator-for-xcode-6)

Comment: Thanks Malloc, my deployment target is iOS 7.1 so it should be OK to use XCode 6 for the iPhone 4 (AFAIK). I am getting the impression that iPhone 4 was just dropped because they don't want you to be able to test anything that can't run iOS8.

Comment: i believe it is not possible. probably because iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s have equal resolution.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Sorry, I could not find that one (not for lack of trying). I'll track down a physical iPhone 4.

Comment: Yeah, iPhone4 was never dropped as it was never there to begin with.  iPhone 4s represents what used to be called "iPhone (Retina)" or something like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Visit apple downloads page, find the older xcode sdk that has iPhone 4 simulator sdk.
2. Copy the simulator sdk from the older xcode to your newer xcode (better create a symbolic link)