# how to deploy and debug an iOS app on iPhone 4 using Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an app which is crashing on iPhone 4 having 7.1 installed , i want to debug app on phone using xcode 6, is it possible(as it shows unavailable currently) ? if not what are the options I am left with ?

Comment: What's the deployment target of the app you want to debug? It needs to be iOS 7.1 or earlier to use that iPhone.

Comment: @rmaddy its minimum 7.1 so thats fine

Comment: What do you mean by "as it shows unavailable currently"?

Comment: @IAmDav when i connect iPhone 4 with os 7.1 on it it gets recognized by Xcode but , it doesn't allow me to run or debug app on it as the OS version on it is lower than the SDK version thus showing that device in the list of emulators/devices as Unavailable.

Comment: Are you sure your deployment targets are set correctly, and the iOS version on the iPhone 4 is 7.1 indeed? I've been able to test like this without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option for an "iPhone 4 Simulator" in Xcode 6. But, if you use an iPhone 4S simulator with iOS 7.1, you can achieve the same effect, because with the same screen size and OS they are essentially the same for testing on the simulator. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069133/iphone-4-simulator-for-xcode-6) for reference.

Of course, if you have a physical iPhone 4, you can also test on the actual device. Make sure that your `Deployment Target` under `TARGETS` AND the `iOS Deployment Target` under `PROJECT` are set to `7.1` or below. Your `Base SDK` can be set higher, but this means you will have to make sure that you are either not using features or classes that are unavailable in earlier versions of iOS, or do a version check and adapt your program accordingly. For example, `UIAlertController` was introduced in iOS 8, and will crash a device below that if it is invoked. So you might want to do a version check and use good old `UIAlertView` if the iOS device version is below 8. An issue like this is the most probable cause of your crash.

Also, if it's the first time you're using this device for development, don't forget to set it up by going to `Window -> Devices`, selecting your connected device, and pressing `Use for development`.

If you don't have the iOS 7.1 SDK and don't see it as a `iPhone 4S (7.1)` in the simulator selection, you need to download it by going to `Preferences -> Downloads`.

Comment: Just to add: In case of simulator you also need to set iOS version from simulator menu: Hardware->Device-> choose iOS version